# How to add proper nouns as vocab to Spacy models?

Tags: python, nlp, named-entity-recognition, spacy

I am using Spacy 1.8.0 with Python and I would like to use Spacy to do analysis on Medical Documents. There is a way off adding new entity types to spacy's named entity recognizer. However, is it possible to add the names of medicines/drugs as proper nouns to spcay's vocab? Or do they need to be added by training the spacy NER? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to do... but below are solutions for a few possibilities.

1. **You have a complete list of the medicines/drugs of interest...**

   i. **and you want a special rule for tokenisation of these strings:** Would not recommend this approach but in principle you could add special cases to the Tokenizer.

   ii. **and you simply want to find them:** Then you should use a Matcher to find them efficiently after you've created the Doc. Then you can do what you want with the spans that you find. Make them pronouns if you want.
2. **You don't have a complete list of the medicines/drugs of interest...**

   i. **but you want to generally identify them:** Then you'll need to train an NER model to recognize them. To generate the training data you could take a whole bunch of papers and use a Matcher looking for known medicines/drugs to grab a whole bunch of example sentences. Then you train...

Later edit: To be clear, the Vocab only stores strings and assigns them a unique ID for working with under the hood. It's the Tagger which decides whether it's a PRON or not.